# Running tests without ssh'ing into my container

Tags: python, docker, pytest

I have a Python API in a docker container, but I want to be able to run tests without sshing in and running the command, but I'm not really sure how I can do that via the command line. For example, I know to ssh in I do (via a script so I can ssh into any of my three containers):

```
docker exec -it gp-api ash
```

but when I want to run tests, I need to ssh in, go up a folder, and then run `pytest`. Not sure how to do that all from the docker command line.

Comment: `docker exec …` has nothing to do with SSH. It is running and a new shell process in the container and not opening an encrypted remote connection to an SSH daemon.

Comment: I find it helpful to have reasonably good standalone unit tests that can be run outside a container, and with as few external dependencies as possible.  That lets you have confidence in your code before you start trying to run it in Docker.

Comment: You're right Klaus, I misspoke on that front.

Comment: @David Maze Yah, but right now, docker is my development environment. It let's me control versions, env vars, etc, meaning it's as clean a dev env as I can get. May not be the right way to look at it, I admit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is stated in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) for the `exec`, you can use `-w` option in the command to set the current working directory.

```
docker exec -w /your/working/directory container_name_or_id command
```

Comment: I admit, I saw that in the docs, but I wasn't sure if that was the right way to do it. I may have been overthinking this...